# C++ classes (public, private, and protected)

Tags: c++, private, public, protected, access-modifiers

How can classes in C++ be declared `public`, `private`, or `protected`?

Comment: As in, do you want someone not to be able to use a class? A class can be subclassed: i.e. class A { private: class B {}; };

Comment: This may be useful to you: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/public-private-protected-c-215399/#post1098220

Comment: Why is there a close vote for this question?  This seems like a perfectly reasonable question to ask.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In C++ there is no notion of an entire class having an access specifier the way that there is in Java or C#.  If a piece of code has visibility of a class, it can reference the name of that class and manipulate it.  That said, there are a few restrictions on this.  Just because you can reference a class doesn't mean you can instantiate it, for example, since the constructor might be marked private.  Similarly, if the class is a nested class declared in another class's private or protected section, then the class won't be accessible outside from that class and its friends.

Answer (score 36):

By nesting one class inside another:

```
class A
{
public:
    class B {};
protected:
    class C {};
private:
    class D {};
};
```

Answer (score 7):

You can implement "private classes" by simply not publishing their interface to clients.

I know of no way to create "protected classes".

Answer (score 6):

It depends if you mean members or inheritance. You can't have a `'private class'`, as such.

```
class Foo
{
public:
Foo() {} //public ctr
protected:
void Baz() //protected function
private:
void Bar() {} //private function
}
```

Or inheritance:

```
class Foo : public Bar
class Foo : protected Bar
class Foo : private Bar
```