# Is a class private or public by default in Java and C++?

Tags: java, c++, class-visibility

Are classes private or public by default in Java and C++?

Answer (score 56):

- **Java**:

  By default, the classes visibility is package private, i.e. only visible for classes in the same package.
- **C++**:

  The class has no visibility defined like in Java. They are visible if you included them to the compilation unit.

Comment: See also answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4855490/2336934

Answer (score 28):

In Java, a *top-level* class is either public or non-public.  There is no "private".  You can only use the public keyword or leave it off.  If you leave it off it is non-public, i.e., visible only to other classes in the same package.

A *nested* class, that is, a class inside of another class, can be made public, package-private, protected, or private, just like any other class member.  The default (i.e., the one with no modifier) is package-private, visible only to classes in the same package.

EDIT: Forgot the C++ answer, so see (and upvote) @zeller's answer. :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment but the link you sent speaks of access modifiers for class members, not the classes themselves. Top level classes cannot be marked private.

Answer (score 16):

According to [§6.6.1 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1),

> If a top level class or interface type is not declared public, then it may be accessed only from within the package in which it is declared.

So, a Java class is by default *package-private*.

This doesn't apply to C++, however. A class lacks visibility -- only its members can have access control. See §11 of the C++11 standard for information on member access control. Here's an excerpt from ¶1...

> A member of a class can be
>
> - `private`; that is, its name can be used only by members and friends of the class in which it is declared.
> - `protected`; that is, its name can be used only by members and friends of the class in which it is
>     declared, by classes derived from that class, and by their friends (see 11.4).
> - `public`; that is, its name can be used anywhere without access restriction.

Comment: +1. Also, in C++ class default member access is `private`, whereas for `struct` it is public.

Answer (score -3):

**Java**

By default Java class is package-private.

**C++**

In C++ there is no visibility defined like Java.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You could improve your answer by explaining what "default" is for Java. I.e., `class Foo` w/o a visibility modifier is package-private. You could also quote https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html or at least link to it. For C++, you could explain on your answer with an example and explanation.