# JAVA Why should a non public class be executable; isn't it being used outside its package?

Tags: java, class, jvm

In Java, I can a run/execute a non public (i.e. 'default' access) java class from the command line even though it is in a package. Why should this be possible? are we not thereby using a default class outside its package which is not supposed to be correct?

Comment: Is the method `public`?

Comment: What do you mean you can "execute" a class? Does your class implement `Runnable` or something?

Comment: can we see the package-class skeleton ??

Comment: From my part, is is not clear. You can only execute a `public static void main(String[])` method from command line (as the [JLS said](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html)). The visibility of the class don't matter ( but I need to confirm that last part )

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. Like the others I am not sure what you are asking for.

Comment: Presuming that you're asking why you can run the `main(String[])` method in a package-private class—why should it be prevented? What advantage would that give?

Comment: private classes are being used outside their context all the time, e.g. nested class `private java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`, returned by `Arrays.asList(...)`, (not to be confused with `public java.util.ArrayList`)

Comment: @KXL: I think this is a good question (and I hope to get some further inputs/ideas to my answer). But it looks like it does get downvotes as it's not very clearly formulated. Could you please try to improve your question?

Answer (score 1):

I think **you're describing** something like the following (See [Is a class private or public by default in Java and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336814/is-a-class-private-or-public-by-default-in-java-and-c) about the available visibility modifiers on a java class):

```
class PkgPrivateClass {

  public void doIt() {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PkgPrivateClass pkgPrivateClass = new PkgPrivateClass();
    pkgPrivateClass.doIt();
  }
}
```

This compiles and prints `Hello World!`.

Now for the question **what is accessible and why**:

- The main method doesn't and can't do anything other than every static method.
- The main method is only **visible inside the same package** (as the class is package private). **Starting a java program** - i.e. calling the main method - is hardly comparable to an **ordinary method call** within a java program.

While package private classes are anyway not used that often (see [Pros and cons of package private classes in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470556/pros-and-cons-of-package-private-classes-in-java#6470746)), I see two arguments why it makes sense to allow calling package private classes from the command line:

- You **explicitly added** the `public static void main(String[] args)` method. If you don't want this class to be called, you don't add this method.
- When starting the JVM, you usually give the **fully qualified** class name. One could argue that this makes the command line call **executed from this package** - or asked the other way around: From what package is a main method called?

Answer (score 0):

The access modifier default has another name which is called as package specific.
So if you are in the same package for a default class you can use command line execution. Outside the package you can not execute default class directly.

Answer (score 0):

main() invoked via reflection, that ignores class visibility. You can write own executor instead of java.exe, that will check class visibility too, or do NOT check visibility of main() for example.